# Android Studio 2.3 Signature Step Verification v1(Jar Signature), v2(Full Apk Signature) Disabled

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-version, signed-apk

Android Studio 2.3 Generate Signed Apk Second Step Signature Verification v1(Jar Signature), v2(Full Apk Signature) How to enabled ?

Signed Apk Second Step screenshot below gradle files:

My build.gradle file is :-

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.revolution.it'
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.0.1'
    compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'

    // Image and file picker
    compile 'com.droidninja:filepicker:1.0.8'

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    debugCompile 'com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.0'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally i found solutions of the problem

v1 or v2 signature varification is enable when i update the gradel version no build.gradle(Proejct Level) 

 `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'`

my old build.gradle( Project Level)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    ........
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    ......
}
```

my **update** build.gradle( Project Level)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
......
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
......
}
```

Comment: Enable both , first i have enable full apk signature but was not able to install on many phone enabling both solved my problem I don't know what's the difference between them and why it got installed on some phone . I had tried full uninstall but didn't worked . Btw i was using signed apk